# How to round up real number in text files in folders in windows or ubuntu

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, command-line

I have folder A which contains many subfolders: X, Y, Z, ...
in each of this folder X, Y, Z, has many text files have the content format like this:

```
1
323 267.6 572 444.6
```

Now I need to round up all the number to it's nearest integer value.
I already tried:

```
xargs -a numbers.txt -n1 printf "%1.f"
```

but it only to print out to the screen.
Now I need to replace the float numbers in the files in the exact position (exact line and position), not to print to screen. How should I do that ?

Comment: first choose tool, as you are ubuntu - python is recommended, cause should be there; list all files you want to edit and then parse each file and when get pattern number replace it with rounded

Comment: PS. there is os.walk to search for files; import re - for regex search in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am using a lot vim, you can try with `ex` command (`vi`)

---

files=`find -L A -type f` ; for f in $files ; do ex -c 'silent! %s:\d+.\d*:\=printf("%.0f",str2float(submatch(0))):g' -c 'wq!' $f;
done

---

First it lists all files inside directory `A` and then it will round the floating number of the form `d.` and `d.d` where `d` is any sequence of digits.

The sample input will be converted to:

> 1
>
> 323 **268** 572 **445**

This solution is not beautiful but it let the work to be done (You may see the terminal blinking caused by -file opening->editing->saving)

Comment: will thi write and replace the number back to the text file ?

Comment: @user1314404 I have edited my answer it should work now.